# PyQt adding a scrollbar to my main window

Tags: pyqt

I want to add a scrollbar to my main window
Here's a simplified version of my code since mine is too long.

```
class Main(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setGeometry(0,0,400,400)
        self.setLayout(verticalLayout)

        label_1 = QtGui.QLabel("label 1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(label_1)
        ...(many more that exceed my computer screen)
```

so I've been reading a lot of posts about scrollbars but I'm still not quite sure as to how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your main window, you need to create a Scroll Area.

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qscrollarea.html

Comment: I wish you'd have been a little bit more specific but nonetheless helped get on track. Thank you.